# How to run multiple .jmx files parallely using jmeter-maven-plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to run different .jmx/jmeter testplans parallely using jmeter-maven-plugin and jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current implementation of JMeter Maven plugin seems to execute tests sequentially, you can consider running your JMeter tests via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a workaround. The command line will be as simple as:

```
bzt test1.jmx test2.jmx test3.jmx ...
```

You can also configure the same using simple [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) syntax.

See [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests) for detailed explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default parallel behaviour built into the plugin.

The way to run multiple files in parallel is to execute multiple maven jobs (with different test cases configured) at the same time.  This lets you set up your memory options for individual tests (although it does add an overhead of multiple maven instances running at the same time)